# Can steam freeze via adiabatic expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, adiabatic, ice

Context:

At the end of animation movie [Steamboy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steamboy), a huge steam engine's pressure vessel breaks, which results in the escaped steam freezing to ice.

I've been thinking about this -- is it really possible to freeze steam through rapid adiabatic expansion to atmospheric pressure? What are the initial steam temperature / pressure conditions allowing for this?

Bonus question: has a catastrophic failure of a steam pressure vessel ever resulted in such an outcome?

Comment: I did very rough calculations, and it seems that for rapid (irreversible) adiabatic expansion, it may not be possible. But I also tried with adiabatic reversible expansion and that might do the trick. I will show my calculations if you want to see them in an answer (but they are very rough, remember).

Comment: I'd be glad to! I got the feeling I could get an answer from h/p charts, but I forgot how to read them... related: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11588/compressing-saturated-steam

Comment: Ah, I got it! I was looking for a T/s chart. in adiabatic expansion, s is constant, so I have to follow the s lines in the chart. Now, to find one for water with low temperatures and labelled phases...

Comment: Haven't seen the movie.  What does "freezing to ice" mean? Does it mean, turns into a cloud of snow? Does it mean coating nearby, cold objects with a thin layer of ice? Does it mean the sudden appearance of a giant cloud-shaped ice sculpture? Does it mean something else? Some of those possibilities seem more plausible than others.

Comment: The movie shows the appearance of a cloud-shaped ice structure, although the cloud of snow scenario looks relevant too (and maybe more realistic ; it's fiction after all...)

Comment: Well, I haven't yet studied about h/p, t/s diagrams. I just did the standard $P^{\gamma-1}T^\gamma = constant$ and some information from wikipedia about pressure (100 atm) inside a high pressure locomotive, and used the temperature at which water would boil at that pressure (600K), for the initial conditions. Plugging in the values seemed to yield a temperature of about 200 K (of course the temperature won't drop down to 200K because there the latent heat to overcome, but it was indicative of formation of ice).

Comment: For irreversible adiabatic, I equated work done by steam to the change in it's internal energy, and used ideal gas equation along with that to find the final temperature, which came around 500 K. I didn't post it as an answer because I think the diagrams may be a better approach and these calculations aren't very accurate ($C_p$ and $C_v$ of water keep changing with P and T, which I haven't accounted for).

Comment: If we admit that this can be described by Joule-Thomson expansion (gas throttling), since enthalpy is constant, we should be able to predict the results on a pressure/enthalpy chart: constant enthalpy, target pressure 1atm with negative celsius temperature (allowing for ice formation).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect